# Pivotal Tracker File Upload : fails

Tags: rest, post, file-upload, pivotaltracker

I am attempting to POST a file to my Pivotal Tracker instance as specified by the [excellent documentation found here](https://www.pivotaltracker.com/help/api#).

I continue to get an "uploaded: False" back from the server.
- My token and project id are correct since I can POST new stories etc..
- My file is in place and accessible by the user running this command

```
fakeuser@fakehost:~/jobs/fakeproject/builds/51$ curl -X POST -H "X-TrackerToken: <mytoken>" -F file=@"/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/changelog.xml" https://www.pivotaltracker.com/services/v5/projects/<projid>/uploads

{
  "kind": "file_attachment",
  "filename": "changelog.xml",
  "created_at": "2013-11-12T14:05:21Z",
  "size": 128,
  "id": 11111111,
  "big_url": "#",
  "content_type": "application/xml",
  "thumbnail_url": "#",
  "uploader_id": 112121212,
  "thumbnailable": false,
  "download_url": "/file_attachments/1212121212/download",
  "uploaded": false
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got an email back from Pivotal Labs with an answer to this question. Thanks Pivotal Labs!

Short answer: 
It's fine, that "false" is just an indicator that the background job to make that file available to your project hasnt happened yet.

From the email
...

> When you upload a file to Tracker, whether via the API or the UI, an
>   asynchronous job has to run to complete the upload and create the
>   thumbnail image. So the immediate response to your request reflects
>   the fact that this job hasn't completed yet. I can see how confusing
>   this is, though.

...